# Strtotime giving different results

Tags: php, linux, strtotime, rhel, centos6.5

So I have a dev box running CentOs6.5 and a server running RHEL 7

if I do the date command from both boxes I get "Mon Sep  8 09:36:50 MDT 2014"
from php if I do echo time(); from both I get 1410190731 within 20seconds of each other.

but if I do strtotime('Sep 8 2014 08:17:00:153AM'); on both boxes I get

1410185820 on CentOS

and

1410164220 on RHEL7

What could cause such a time difference on strtotime() and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: `Sep 8 2014 08:17:00:153AM'` is an invalid date as there is no such thing a 153 seconds. Fix that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving a second set of seconds to the date instead of setting it as milliseconds. Try: `strtotime('Sep 8 2014 08:17:00.153 AM');`